# Does the 3DS version of Luigi's Mansion keep track of how many times the game is cleared?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, luigis-mansion

The GameCube version of Luigi's Mansion shows a counter for how many times you've cleared the game on a given save file, but I can't find this in the 3DS version. Is this feature still in the game, and if so, where is it?